# How to get a href from a td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm quite new to jQuery and ran into a problem I can't solve.
I need to get a href that I want to select via a parant td with two classes.
Important: There a several occurrences in the code from that class, I need to select the FIRST.
Here is the HTML Code:

```
<td class="trackerList small>
  <a href="index.php?moduleAccounts......."> (...) </a>
</td>
```

Here is my jQuery Selector (that obviously doesn't work - alert just for testing):

```
var a_href = jQuery('.trackerListBullet.small').first().child().attr('href');
alert (a_href);
```

Thanks a lot, tried for more than two hours now but can't find the right selecor...

Comment: Why are you referring to . trackerListBullet when your parent node is trackerList? Have you tried $('. trackerList a') then access the href attribute?

Comment: Hey Stephen, thanks for the hint - that was just a typing mistake :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var a_href = jQuery('td.trackerList.small:first a').attr('href');
  alert(a_href);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="trackerList small">
      <a href="index.php?moduleAccounts1"> (...) </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="trackerList small">
      <a href="index.php?moduleAccounts2"> (...) </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This :-

```
var a_href = jQuery('td.trackerList.small').find('a:first').attr('href');
alert (a_href);
```